# In sql, how to always insert data in a table with concurrency?

Tags: sql, concurrency, insert

In sql how to always insert data in a table with concurrency? Must ensure that the data is received, example table "Bet", all the app clients of that database server must have de ensure that their bet is placed.

Comment: What database? What language? What platform? What are you talking about? Please provide some more context around the scenario you are looking for or the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What database are you using? Is it ACID-compliant? How are the applications accessing the data? What, exactly, are you trying to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On an INSERT statement, the only way to not have concurrency is to violate some kind of constraint.  As long as you have declared the constraint (primary key, not null, foreign key, etc), the database will throw an error on any violation.

I'm not sure what API you are using to talk to the database, but it will certainly signal in some way that a database error has occurred.  Then you need to handle that case appropriately by informing the application to invalidate the data.

Comment: Some DBMS (e.g. MySQL with MyISAM) won't allow concurrent writes to the same table (due to table locking)